# What's the benefit of Apple having used struct with static properties (instead of enum) for UITextContentType?

Tags: swift, struct, enums, uikit, uitextfield

In Swift, Apple's `UITextContentType` is a struct with many static properties of type `UITextContentType` such as:

- `static let URL: UITextContentType`
- `static let addressCity: UITextContentType`
- `static let addressCityAndState: UITextContentType`

etc.

But UIKit/UITextInputTraits.h has:

`typedef NSString * UITextContentType NS_TYPED_ENUM;`

And I notice that within Swift, the compiler infers `UITextContentType`, allowing you to simply use `.URL` or `.addressCityAndState` instead of `UITextContentType.URL` or `UITextContentType.addressCityAndState` for any function argument that takes type `UITextContentType` (thereby treating it just like an enum).

So why didn't they just use an `enum` to begin with? What's the advantage of using this pattern...? When would we want to use this pattern in our own code?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed Apple does this with SKAction as well. Every action is a static property.
I wish they had used enum in this case. <sup><sub><sup><sub>ha</sub></sup></sub></sup>

There are a few differences between *Static Properties* and *Enum Cases*.

But really it's up to you with how you want to use them.

---

**Pros of Static Properties**

 • You don't have to make a switch statement every time you want a raw value

 • Raw Values can contain mutating non-literal values.

 • Static Properties can be whatever type you want it to be `static let a = 5, b = false`

 • You can add static properties to enums, structs, classes, protocols

**Cons of Static Properties**

 • They can not have 'stored properties' like non-static values

 • They are not CaseIterable

---

**Pros of Enum**

 • You can store values inside cases `case hello(String, [Bool])`

 • You can have recursive stored properties using indirect enum

 • Cases can be CaseIterable

**Cons of Enum**

 • You cannot have multiple rawValue types `case foo = "5", bar = 5`

 • Raw Value types cannot contain values. `case foo = "\(5)"`

 • Those tricky switch case statements everywhere

 • You cannot add enum cases to non-enum objects